# Why in ngx-ui-loader during httprequest spinner (background-spinner), user is able to access the application?

Tags: angular, spinner, angular7, ngx-ui-loader

How to stop the user from accessing page when the spinner is going on in ngx-ui-loader during httpclient request?

angular 7

Expected result: User should not able to access/interact with the application when ngx-ui-loader (background-spinner) is going on.

Actual result: User able to interact/access page when background-spinner is going on. In the case of Foreground-spinner, the user not able to access the page as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very simple, we need to add foreground spinner even during httprequest. Like this in app.module.ts > import >

```
NgxUiLoaderHttpModule.forRoot({showForeground:true})
```

which helped to stop user to interact with UI while spinner is going on.